# Can t run android application on eclipse neon

Tags: android, eclipse

I can t run Android apps on eclipse neon. Only 'run as' java... junit. And i can t select the projects on 'run configuration'. 
Diffuculty, also to create new project (android resources manager pb).
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I thought Google stopped supporting the Android plugin for eclipse. I would recommend using Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html